# Unity Parse.com retrieve updatedAt into variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parse-platform

I am trying to figure out how to retrieve the updatedAt from parse into my Unity app and convert it to a string. Here is what I have tried:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery("TurnTime");
query.GetAsync("StSHxHCczO").ContinueWith(t =>
                                           {
    ParseObject theTurnTimer = t.Result;

    DateTime? updatedAt1 = theTurnTimer.UpdatedAt;
    string testTime1 = updatedAt1.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    Debug.Log("Test1: "+testTime1);

    DateTime updatedAt1 = theTurnTimer.Get<DateTime>("createdAt");
    string testTime2 = updatedAt1.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    Debug.Log("Test2: "+testTime2);

});
```

I know that I do have the Object but I do not get any things in my debug.logs? Is there something I am missing here?

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance :-)

####### EDIT

After investigating further I have this to add:

I can't convert DateTime? to string like in the first example:

```
DateTime? updatedAt1 = theTurnTimer.UpdatedAt;
string testTime1 = updatedAt1.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
```

In the second part I don't get to the Debug.Log:

```
DateTime updatedAt1 = theTurnTimer.Get<DateTime>("createdAt");
string testTime2 = updatedAt1.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
Debug.Log("Test2: "+testTime2);
```

So I still haven't found the solution and any help is still appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "I don't get any things"?  Do you get any debug output at all?

Comment: @stromdotcom - I have updated my post with issues I didn't get the first time, and no... I do not get any Debug.Log :-/